# How to view SearchKit's API and SQL

Tags: searchkit

I was following along the [1st video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WAAaBsJQsE&list=PLjSU7YfE0E028kuK948i7_qxUlbHZbfJR&index=1) of the [SearchKit playlist on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjSU7YfE0E028kuK948i7_qxUlbHZbfJR). And approximately 38 min in, the presenter shows how one can see the underlying API code or SQL code for a given search. It looks like he simply expanded on a tab, Query Info. However this is not available for me on my Buildkit site and I'm wondered how to enable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need "CiviCRM: view debug output" permission in the CMS.

Also if it's not obvious, you have to run the search first before it appears.

Comment: Just what I needed - thanks!